# Blender instantly closes on startup

Tags: error

This has started today, and I'm not sure what happened, since I had been using 2.83.2 for a while.
The process is as depicted: I click on either the Blender shortcut, or the direct .exe file, it boots up the command tab, and then it closes.
I have tried using other versions, these don't work either. It may be a problem I've had in the past where Blender 2.83 closed because I tried copying the preferences from 2.82.

I'm pretty sure it's not a performance problem, but I'll tell this if it helps.

Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070
i7-8750H
32 GB of RAM
8 GB of VRAM

Comment: Generic suggestion: try updating any device drivers on your PC, and try reinstalling Blender itself.  May be easier than trying to figure out what actually went wrong...

Comment: Start blender from the command line, if it crashes it usually prints an error into the cmd

Comment: WhatAMesh, how should I do it? Like, I guess I have to enter a command in either python or cmd but I don't know which

Comment: Should the issue reoccur, I would suggest you follow [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports/173685#173685) to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution to this all along was restarting my PC, which I didn't think would fix the problem so I didn't try in the first place.

Comment: If its not just some generic bug there maybe be a misplaced EXIT python command in some plugin you are using. If not directly they may be calling some module with one. Thats happened to me. It was only being called under very circumstances so it was torture to debug.